# about Http Live Streaming protocol issue

Tags: http-live-streaming

Our project has been rejected twice because of 9.4(from App Store Review Guidelines).They said we didn't use the Http Live Streaming protocol...

we have already download the Validator Tools as they mentioned in the document(http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2235/_index.html),but when I use it in the Terminal,the result is not act like what they wrote in the document(http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2224/_index.html),it just showed the first three lines information,that't sth about the Average Segment Bitrate,but there's no result about the Audio Bitrate and Video Bitrate,so...I don't know why,is there sth wrong with the tool?or I used the wrong method?

For clearing my question,I'll list the result below:

this is the official document result show,as you can find it in "http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2224/_index.html"

```
Validating   http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear3/prog_index.m3u8against iOS 3.1.0

Average segment duration: 8.77 seconds
Average segment bitrate: 510.05 kbit/s
Average segment structural overhead: 96.37 kbit/s (18.89 %)

Video codec: avc1
Video resolution: 480x360 pixels
Video frame rate: 29.97 fps
Average video bitrate: 407.76 kbit/s
H.264 profile: Baseline
H.264 level: 2.1

Audio codec: aac 
Audio sample rate: 22050 Hz
Average audio bitrate: 5.93 kbit/s
```

and the following message is my testing result:

```
Average segment duration: 9.79 seconds
Average segment bitrate: 74109.89 bps
```

Thanks for answering in advance!

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: @vipw Thanks for your reply. My question is that when I typed "mediastreamvalidator validate http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear3/prog_index.m3u8" in the Terminal on Mac OS,all I can see the result is only two lines information as you can see above, but the official documentation shows a lot of information, like Video codec,H.264 level etc.

Comment: @vipw what I want to know is to how to show the left information, like Video bitrate, Audio bitrate or sth like that.